# assigning value from smarty plugins

Tags: smarty, smarty3

I have caching enabled on my smarty installation and have following Template Functions

```
function smarty_updatedhour($params, $smarty)
{
    $date1 = new DateTime($params['timestamp']);
    $date2 = new DateTime("now");
    $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
    $smarty->assign("updated_period", $interval->format('%h'), true);
}
```

I have registered the plugin as:

```
$smarty->registerPlugin('function', 'updated_hour', 'smarty_updatedhour', false, array('timestamp'));
```

I tried to test it whether it is working or not

```
{updated_hour timestamp=$timestamp_vale}
{$updated_period}
{if $updated_period > 10}
    // do other stuffs
{/if}
```

but it does not work however when I disable the smarty page caching, it works.

can anyone tell me what is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Smarty3 your plugins work with the template, not the smarty object. So your function's footprint is `function smarty_updatehour(array $params, Smarty_Internal_Template $template)`. That's not your problem, though. Even the assignGlobal() hint by @sudhir won't help you one bit.

your non-caching plugin cannot assign variables, but return the actual output:

```
function smarty_updatedhour($params, $smarty)
{
    $date1 = new DateTime($params['timestamp']);
    $date2 = new DateTime("now");
    $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
    return $interval->format('%h');
}
```

that is because {$updated_period} is not non-caching. That output is evaluated EXACTLY ONCE and then written to cache. Either try `{nocache}{$updated_period}{/nocache}` or go with the modified plugin code above.

Comment: well, I can not return the function output. It's because the assigned value is further processed on template with {if}{/if} and the assigned value in real is not meant for displaying within template. So from your suggestion the only possibility is to wrap my variable output (for testing) or {if} conditions within {nocache}. Also note that, I did set nocache to true while assigning updated_period on my plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try using assignGlobal, like:

```
$smarty->assignGlobal("updated_period", $interval->format('%h'), true);
```

Hope it works for you